# Activity presenter will update the tablayout fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, rx-java, android-tablayout

I have an Activity1 with a TabLayout of two Fragments (each of them with a presenter). Once I click a button on the Toolbar a new Activity2 is started (with startActivityWithResults) which contains a simple list. At the selection of one of the items in the list the Activity2 returns the selected string to the previous Activity1 (the one with the TabLayout).

Now, once onActivityResult is called in Activity1, this one will call an API (using a presenter) that will get the new results and then it should update the two fragments in the TabLayout. I'm thinking to do it with RxJava but I have no idea where to start from.

The Activity1:

```
public class Activity1 extends BaseActivity {

@Inject
Actvity1Presenter mPresenter;

public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext) {
    return new Intent(packageContext, Activity1.class);
}

@LayoutRes
protected int getLayoutRedIs() {
    return R.layout.app_bar_activity1;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutRedIs());

    FwApplication.component(this).inject(this);

    mPresenter.attachView(this);

    Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_chips);
    setSupportActionBar(tb);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back_arrow);

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB1"));
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB2"));
    mTabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            mTabLayout.getTabCount()));
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));
    mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_ITEM_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mPresenter.updateResults(data);
        }

        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

        }
    }
}
```

And the pager:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

int mNumOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
      case 0:
        return Fragment1.newInstance();
        break;
      case 1:
        return Fragment2.newInstance();
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```

**EDIT**

ActivityPresenter:

```
public class ActivityPresenter implements Presenter<ActivityView>,
    Interactor.OnFinishedListener<Response> {

private static final String TAG = "FW.ActivityPresenter";

@Inject
QueryPreferences mQueryPreferences;

private Interactor mInteractor;
private ActivityView mView;
private NetworkService mNetworkService;
private boolean mUseCache;
private String mQuery;
private int mPage;

private PublishSubject<Response> mPublishSubject =   PublishSubject.create();

Observable<Response> getObservableResults() {
   return mPublishSubject;
}

@Inject
public ActivityPresenter(NetworkService networkService) {
    mNetworkService = networkService;
    mInteractor = new InteractorImpl(mNetworkService);
}

public void onSearchQueryListener(String query, int page) {
    mQuery = mQueryPreferences.getStoredQuery();
    mUseCache = query.equals(mQuery);

    if (!mUseCache) {
        mQueryPreferences.setStoredQuery(query);
        Log.d(TAG, "Query added to cache: " + query);
    }

    mPage = page;
    mInteractor.loadResults(this, query, false, page);
}

@Override
public void onFinished(Response response) {
    if (mView != null) {
       mPublishSubject.onNext(response);
    }
}

@Override
public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
    if (mView != null) {
        mView.showMessage(throwable.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void attachView(ActivityView mvpView) {
    mView = mvpView;
}

@Override
public void detachView() {
    mView = null;
    mInteractor.unSubscribe();
}
}
```

InteractorImpl:

```
public class InteractorImpl implements Interactor {

private static final String TAG = "FW.InteractorImpl";

private NetworkService mNetworkService;
private Subscription mSubscription;

public InteractorImpl(NetworkService networkService) {
    mNetworkService = networkService;
}

@Override
public void loadResults(final OnFinishedListener listener, String query, boolean useCache, int page) {
    Observable<Response> responseObservable = (Observable<Response>)
            mNetworkService.getObservable(mNetworkService.getAPI().getResponseObservable(query, page), Response.class, true, useCache);

    mSubscription = responseObservable.subscribe(new Observer<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            listener.onError(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Response response) {
            listener.onFinished(response);
        }
    });
}

public void unSubscribe() {
    if(mSubscription != null && !mSubscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
        mSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
}
```

FragmentPresenter:

```
public class FragmentPresenter implements Presenter<FragmentView>,
    Interactor.OnFinishedListener<Response> {

private static final String TAG = "FW.FragmentPres";

@Inject
QueryPreferences mQueryPreferences;

private Interactor mInteractor;
private FragmentView mView;
private NetworkService mNetworkService;

private ActivityPresenter mActvityPresenter;

@Inject
public FragmentPresenter(NetworkService networkService) {
    mNetworkService = networkService;
    mInteractor = new InteractorImpl(mNetworkService);
}

void attachRecipeActivityPresenter(ActivityPresenter activityPresenter) {
    mActvityPresenter = activityPresenter;
    mActvityPresenter.getObservableResults().subscribe(data -> showData(data));
}

private void showData(Response response) {
    if (response.getResults().getModels().isEmpty() && mPage == 0) {
        mView.showNoResults();
    } else {
        mView.showResults(response.getResults().getModels());
    }
}

@Override
public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
    if (mView != null) {
        mView.hideProgressBar();
        mView.showMessage(throwable.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void attachView(FragmentView mvpView) {
    mView = mvpView;
}

@Override
public void detachView() {
    mView = null;
    mInteractor.unSubscribe();
}
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Retrofit2 and RxAndroid your method will look like this:

```
public void updateResults(String data) {
    yourRetrofitAPI.getSomething(data)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe(() -> {
                // show your progress dialog
            })
            .subscribe(result -> {
                // pass result to your view
            }, error -> {
                // hide your progress dialog
                // get error message and send to your view
            }, () -> {
                // hide your progress dialog
            });
}

interface YourRetrofitAPI {
    @GET("/yourResource/{data}")
    Observable<String> getSomething(@Path("data") String data);
}
```

So, about notify your fragments, with MVP you can make presenter fragments observe a stream from activity presenter, so both fragments will be notified when you query ends.

```
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void testSample() throws Exception {
        ActivityPresenter activityPresenter = new ActivityPresenter();

        Fragment1Presenter fragment1Presenter = new Fragment1Presenter();
        Fragment2Presenter fragment2Presenter = new Fragment2Presenter();

        fragment1Presenter.attachActivityPresenter(activityPresenter);
        fragment2Presenter.attachActivityPresenter(activityPresenter);

        Observable.range(1, 10)
                .delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.immediate())
                .subscribe(integer -> activityPresenter.queryData("query: " + integer));
    }

    class ActivityPresenter {
        PublishSubject<String> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

        Observable<String> serverDataAsObservable() {
            return publishSubject.map(s -> String.format("%d - %s", System.currentTimeMillis(), s));
        }

        void queryData(String input) {
            // based on your input you should query data from server
            // and then emit those data with publish subject
            // then all subscribers will receive changes
            publishSubject.onNext(input);
        }
    }

    class Fragment1Presenter {
        private ActivityPresenter activityPresenter;

        void attachActivityPresenter(ActivityPresenter activityPresenter) {
            this.activityPresenter = activityPresenter;
            this.activityPresenter.serverDataAsObservable()
                    .subscribe(data -> showData(data));
        }

        private void showData(String data) {
            System.out.println("showing data on fragment1 with " + data);
        }
    }

    class Fragment2Presenter {
        private ActivityPresenter activityPresenter;

        void attachActivityPresenter(ActivityPresenter activityPresenter) {
            this.activityPresenter = activityPresenter;
            this.activityPresenter.serverDataAsObservable()
                    .subscribe(data -> showData(data));
        }

        private void showData(String data) {
            System.out.println("showing data on fragment2 with " + data);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that it helps.

Best regards.

Comment: Rodrigo, thanks for your answer. Though my question is a bit different. Consider that I have basically a SearchView and below it a TabLayout. So depending on what you search the results in the fragments in the tabLayout change. So basically what I want to understand is how the SearchView can update the two fragments after receiving the results. So one call (using Retrofit) --> 2 fragments updated

Comment: You could make your ActivityPresenter communicate with yours fragments presenters. Then you pass the data and show into fragments.

Comment: How can the activityPresenter communicate with the fragments presenters? Interface and then callback?

Comment: I was thinking that using Observer could be easier or cleaner..what do you think?

Comment: It's a complex architecture. You can create a Observable into your ActivityPresenter and expose it to yous fragments presenter

Comment: They will subscribe to stream and every time your data changed you just emit a new item to them

Comment: Your ActivityPresenter has a Stream that your fragment presenters will subscribe. I believe that it is what you are looking for.

Comment: I've used a similar architecture in my project. I have a Stream that I expose with Dagger and then I can subscribe to it in any presenter

Comment: You just have to take care with subscription lifecycle. I recommend you to use RxLifecycle.

Comment: Do you have an example of github for me in order to understand better? I'm still trying to learn RxJava and sometimes it makes me confused. If not, no worries and thanks for your answers!

Comment: I will update my answer in order to show you how to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I will check it out and try to apply to my project!

Comment: Rodrigo, I updated my question with some code I wrote. I'm a bit unsure how to expose the stream or the observable with Dagger in order to use it in the fragments (I'm stuck basically in the fragment since how don't know how to subscribe the event)

Comment: I noticed that my main problem is where to attach the ActivityPresenter to the FragmentPresenter

Comment: You can attach in onCreateView method